# How can I pipe the output of 'find' into a command that will execute 'more' piped into 'grep' on package.json two directories up?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I am trying to find which package.json is causing a dependency warning. It's coming from a sub-module. I have a find command `find . -name 'foo'` that outputs

```
/a/very/very/very/long/path/to/a/submodule/.../node_modules/foo
/another/very/very/very/long/path/to/a/submodule/.../node_modules/foo
```

I want to see what version of foo is included in the parent module's package.json. Something like this

`more "$find_output"/../../package.json | grep foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
find . -name 'foo' -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for path; do more "$path"/../../package.json | grep "foo"; echo $path; done ' bash
```